# Unable to recognise the Live stream voice using sphinx4

Tags: java, macos-catalina, sphinx4

I have created code based on this
[tutorial](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/)

Performing Speech to text from a .wav file using StreamSpeechRecognizer works fine but I am facing an issue with `LiveSpeechRecognizer`, In debug the code goes till         `recognizer.startRecognition(true);` and never moves further, I am running this on IntelliJ and using macOS Catalina

I suspect macOS or java is not allowing the file to use a microphone.

Code :

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
recognizer.startRecognition(true);
SpeechResult result ;

while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
    System.out.println("speech recognition started");
    System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
}
recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

Comment: Not to discourage, but I got sphinx4 working and found it to be unusable anyway. It picked up words occasionally but was absolutely hopeless at anything more than one or two syllables.